# translate Wordpress site and Change Header Image on one button click

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I am stuck to perform two tasks on single button. Can anyone help me to solve my issue:

I have two header images in Greek and English.

Issue is that, the header image changes according the site language. If web is in Greek language header image must be in Greek and if site language is English header image must be in English.

WordPress Website: https://www.pointofbeauty.gr/

I am using Elementor builder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the language in html  and  and write styles like:

```
[lang="el"] #english-image {display: none;} 
[lang="en"] #english-image {display: block;}
```